# Drupal: Associating grouping more than one CCK field

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, cck

I have an article content type with a node reference CCK field that links to other articles (related articles) .

I need to add a text field for each node reference that allows an admin to specify "why it's related". How do I go about this in D6?

Articles can be related with other articles so it makes sense to have the "why it's related" to go in the main article referencing the related articles.

This is using the text area type ahead so that the user will be given teh drag and drop UI for reordering.

Ideally it would be something like:

*related article 1

*Why it's related.

////

*related article 2

*why it's related 2.

//////

....

The last ditch effort is to not have them associated and then the admin just makes sure that the line up.  Not nearly as great of a user experience, but workable I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with CCK 3.x, using the Multigroup module that comes with it. Note that this doesn't have a stable release at this point, but will work fine for most use cases.