# a way to create a dynamic loop for a drupal cck field with multiple values

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, cck, drupal-theming

i have a list of links that i want to print similar to [Drupal: Associating grouping more than one CCK field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194772/drupal-associating-grouping-more-than-one-cck-field) but the multigroup module is no longer active (as of like a month after that post) i have been printing them like so:

```
<?php if($node->field_committee_link[0][value]): ?><h4>1) <a href="<?php print $node->field_committee_link[0][value] ?>"><?php print $node->field_committee_link[0][value] ?></a></h4><?php endif; ?>
<?php if($node->field_link_descriptor[0][value]): ?><?php print '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'. $node->field_link_descriptor[0][value] ?><?php endif; ?>
```

and changing the numbers

is their a way to loop through such as

for $node->field_committee_link[0][value] to $node->field_committee_link[x][value]
print $node->field_committee_link[x][value]
x= i++
next

or would i need to preprocess this?

help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try...

```
foreach ($node->field_committee_link as $link) {
  print $link[value];
}
```